# sklearn SGDClassifier, results a label when no match available?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification

I am using sklearn SGDClassifier for predicting my data set.
I have text which should not be classified in any label/category, but I am amazed, if I am giving test data as "kjhd askdhajksdh asd askh", it is still getting classified to one of the given categories.

I have worked with probabilities as well but still having a valuable probability for this junk text.

My question is, can classifier return something like "No match found" etc for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

No. Classifier will classify any input to one of the labels in training with the highest probability, however small are these probabilities.

You can use [decision_function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.decision_function) for setting a threshold of a label. 
Something like:

```
threshold = 0.25
if confidence_score < threshold:
    print("No match found")
```